# Subdomain of subdomain? How is it possible?

Tags: url, domains, subdomain

I saw a subdomain of a subdomain:  `meta.unix.stackexchange.com`
How is it possible?

Because in hosting/dns providers I only can configure subdomains, not subdomains of subdomains, i.e.: `subdomain.example.com`, etc...

If I buy a domain name or even a free no-ip.org subdomain i.e.: `example.no-ip.org` will I be able to configure with *bind9* in Ubuntu per example this scheme: `subsubdomain.example.no-ip.org`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible exactly the same way that `unix.stackexchange.com` itself is possible. **DNS does not impose any specific hierarchy,** like "subdomain – domain – toplevel", you can add as many labels as you need, and add delegations at any level.

(Take "www.theregister.co.uk" for example. Is "theregister.co.uk" a domain or a subdomain? *It's both.*)

In other words, the administrators just added "meta.unix.stackexchange.com" to their DNS management software.

- For example, in a BIND zone file it might look like this:

  ```
  ...
  unix.stackexchange.com.      A 198.252.206.140
  meta.unix.stackexchange.com. A 198.252.206.140
  ...
  ```

  (This lets you see that all levels are functionally equivalent.)
- Or like this:

  ```
  $ORIGIN stackexchange.com.
  ...
  unix      A 198.252.206.140
  meta.unix A 198.252.206.140
  ...
  ```

So there's a chance that your DNS control panel also allows entering "meta.unix" as a subdomain name. If it doesn't, that's a completely *artificial* limit decided by your host – DNS itself allows 127 total "levels" (each individual label up to 63 bytes, the complete name up to 253 bytes).

For example, No-IP might have such a limit for marketing/business reasons (to make you buy an actual *domain* instead of freely creating subdomains off the shared ones.)

---

For similar reasons, you'll only be able to use bind9 (or nsd, djbdns...) with a purchased domain, not with a No-IP subdomain.

- Technically, No-IP *could* delegate a subdomain to your own bind9 server – it's as simple as adding NS-type records like you would add A/AAAA/CNAME ones:

  ```
  foobar.no-ip.org.  NS ns1.fakeisp.com.
  foobar.no-ip.org.  NS ns2.fakeisp.com.
  ```

  (Side note: Yes, NS records only accept names, not IP addresses. For this reason, if you self-host the domain on your own DNS servers, you would need a "glue record":

  ```
  quux.no-ip.org.    NS ns.quux.no-ip.org.
  ns.quux.no-ip.org. A  172.16.42.42
  ```

  But that's a topic for another post.)
- But in practice, they won't, for business reasons – they *do* sell domain names, after all.

Answer (score 3):

> **I saw a subdomain of a subdomain:  meta.unix.stackexchange.com**

That is normal, a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) can have a large number of elements. The DNS protocol and most (probably all) DNS server implementations allow you to delegate subdomains to arbitrary depth. I think until you hit the 255-character hard limit on the length of a FQDN. each element must be no more than 63 characters long.

For example DNS would let some eccentric admin create

```
www.tablet-layout.windows.95.us.deleted.meta.unix.stackexchange.com
```

And still have "A" records at intermediate levels.

**How is it possible?**

The way I used to create subdomains when I ran the top level of a corporate DNS service was to delegate subdomains, often to other servers but sometimes to the same nameserver but keeping the subdomain data separated into distinct zonefiles. This was using BIND.

I would never have dreamed of using a dot in a node name.

```
The following syntax will result in fewer problems with many applications 
that use domain names (e.g., mail, TELNET).

<domain> ::= <subdomain> | " "

<subdomain> ::= <label> | <subdomain> "." <label>

<label> ::= <letter> [ [ <ldh-str> ] <let-dig> ]

<ldh-str> ::= <let-dig-hyp> | <let-dig-hyp> <ldh-str>

<let-dig-hyp> ::= <let-dig> | "-"

<let-dig> ::= <letter> | <digit>

<letter> ::= any one of the 52 alphabetic characters A through Z 
             in upper case and a through z in lower case

<digit> ::= any one of the ten digits 0 through 9
```

Note that this does not provide for dots in labels. Software that supports this is probably effectively creating subdomains under the hood.

---

> 3. DOMAIN NAME SPACE and RESOURCE RECORDS

> 3.1. Name space specifications and terminology

> The domain name space is a tree structure.  Each node and leaf on the
> tree corresponds to a resource set (which may be empty).  **The domain
> system makes no distinctions between the uses of the interior nodes and
> leaves**, and this memo uses the term "node" to refer to both.

> Each node has a label, which is zero to 63 octets in length.  Brother
> nodes may not have the same label, although the same label can be used
> for nodes which are not brothers.  One label is reserved, and that is
> the null (i.e., zero length) label used for the root.

See

- [DNS - Concepts and Facilities](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034)
- [BIND: how to delegate subzone to other DNS server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/170231/bind-how-to-delegate-subzone-to-other-dns-server)

Comment: I was so used to delegating zones to far-flung outposts of the empire that I would have naturally just used the same technique for any local names of that type. Plus I would have have been careful to follow the guidance in the RFCs rather than use features that might conceivably be not well supported in a multinational, os-agnostic, multi-vendor, open-systems corporation with 300000 employees in 70 countries many of whose DNS admins I had to converse with over the phone despite language issues and with whom I would therefore prefer to keep things simple and regular. YMMV!