# How can the domain portion of an email address have three dots?

Tags: domains, subdomain, email

Please check this email address:

```
visa.tav@a.b.c.d
```

I expected that the domain name (`a.b.c.d`) would have only one dot or only two dots, but it has three dots.

How can this be explained?

Comment: As Maximilllian explains.  An example would be hello@shop.example.com.au

Comment: Re-evaluate your expectations? You have not advised why your expectations are as they are.  As long as the domain has a valid MX record set up in DNS (arguably an MX record or resolves to an IP) this is totally fine.

Comment: "How can this be explained?" How can what be explained? You seem to have some false expectations on what a domain name is (the right part of an email address). It may help explaining more what you think is a problem there, but discussing a real email address besides a badly obfuscated one, could also give more power to your question, and hence its answers.

Answer (score 2):

The part that comes after the "@" is a **domain name**, and domain names can contain any number of dots as per the DNS (domain name system) specification. Each dot denotes a new name space within the space of the previous one, all the way up to the root zone, for example, "com".

See this related question for more context around domains with multiple levels:

[Subdomain of subdomain? How is it possible?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77534/subdomain-of-subdomain-how-is-it-possible)